# Suggestion for better relational DB Schema

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I am here to design a relational database schema that models polling and users. Each
category can have one or many questions. Each user can participate
only once at each category, and can poll (or not) exactly once on
each question. Each poll is yes, no, or abstain (no vote).

I have designed my schema with four tables:

```
 users, [userId, IP]
 category, [catId, catTitle]
 question, [queId, queTitle]
 polls [pollId, queId, userId, answer]
```

is better or

```
 users, [userId, IP]
 category, [catId, catTitle]
 question, [queId, queTitle]
 polls [pollId, catId, userId]
 pollAnswers [pollAndId, queId, pollId, answer]
```

I would like to know which one is better and why?

as per me since i dun have any extra information about polls i am directly cross joining users and questions with answer.

I also do need to find how many users were abstain for a.) all category question b.) particular category c.) particular question

I have my view as for choice one schema :

```
select U1.*, Q1.*, P2.*, C1.*
from 
    ( users U1, 
    questions Q1 )
    Left outer Join polls P2 on 
        Q1.queId = P2.queId AND U1.userId = P2.userId
    Left Outer Join category C1 on
        Q1.catId = C1.catId
```

I am trying to worried using above query with cross join between users and question will loose my performance or not?

If second schema is better can u suggest options for my results?

Comment: This doesn't really help your schema, but I think abbreviated field names are horrendous. Also, why prefix each field name with the table's name? Why not users(id, ip), questions(id, body), polls(id, question_id, user_id, answer)?

Comment: thxn for suggestion to remove abbreviated field names. next i dun get you saying "this doesn't really help your schema" what does it mean

Comment: they mean removing the prefixes doesn't help your schema however it does make it more readable. And you should use "don't" instead of "dun".

Comment: thanks... i will keep it on my mind

Comment: Just another quick comment you are missing any relationship between the question and the category. So you need to add: catId to the `question` table.

I'll have a crack later at your select queries. :D

Answer (score -1):

users: rename to user so all entities are singular (or rename the singulars to plural)

category: OK

question: You need a foreign key from question to category

pollAnswers: Rename to pollAnswer, and make it a reference table with three rows: Yes, No, Abstain

polls: Rename to poll, and make this a transaction of a user polling a question, with foreign keys to user, question, and pollAnswer.

(Options: Either validate on insert that the user has no existing polls for questions in the category, or denormalize PollAnswers with the question's foreign key to category and put a unique constraint on user/question.  I don't personally like this option because it presents issues if you change the category of a question.)

Then a query for a particular category could look like this:

```
select *
from category c
LEFT OUTER JOIN question q ON q.catID = c.catID
LEFT OUTER JOIN poll p ON p.queId = q.queId
LEFT OUTER JOIN user u ON u.userId = p.UserID
WHERE c.catID = 'blah blah'
```